# Gradient Boosting Classifier-n_estimators

Tags: python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, gradient, gradient-descent, boosting

I am trying Gradient Boosting Classifier for my project. I am using 100 samples. I have used Leave one out cross validation. As far as i know, GBC should give good results with large n_estimators. But i am getting low results with large n-estimators.Where am i going wrong. Thank you
I have tried the following:

tried:n_estimators=100, learning_rate=1.0,max_depth=1, random_state=0 
  result:Accuracy=0.635416666667 AUC=0.5703125

tried: tried:n_estimators=200, learning_rate=1.0,max_depth=1, random_state=0
result:Accuracy=0.625  AUC=0.5546875

tried:n_estimators=1, learning_rate=1.0,max_depth=1, random_state=0
result:Accuracy=0.739583333333 AUC=0.6640625

Comment: what is "efficiency"?

Comment: lejlot- Sorry, it is accuracy not efficiency.